# How to build only master branch using circleci

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I am using circle ci and I would like to run pipeline only for master. But it is not working.

My config is:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    filters:
      branches:
        only:
          - master
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:13.2.0
```

What is wrong? Pipeline start for are branches.

Comment: Take a look at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/, you seem to be mixing up top-level and within-workflow job objects.

Comment: It is what I found in doc.- https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#branches

Comment: Exactly; that shows jobs.<name>.branches, you have jobs.<name>.filters.branches.

Answer (score 5):

You should use filter in workflow section as below.

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-publish:
    jobs:
      - publish:   
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 1):

CircleCI has now added the possibility to filter both workflows and jobs by branch ([documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/using-branch-filters/)). So previously you could only do this in workflows:

```
workflows:
  build:
    when:
      and:
        - equal: [ master, << pipeline.git.branch >> ]
    jobs:
      - build
```

and now you can do the same in jobs.

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:13.2.0
    steps:
      - when:
          condition:
            equal: [ master, << pipeline.git.branch >> ]
    ...
```

both should work as expected and only run when on master branch.

Comment: This seems a lot more complex than the older answer (though of course, this is more versatile if what you actually need requires more complex conditionals).